# Does Firebase query everytime from server

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Cloud Firestore database in my Android app. (I'm using Android SDK). When the app starts I query the logged in users data and as the document states, a copy is stored locally.

If the document data does not change, when I query .get document, will Firebase always query the server or return from the local copy? The reason I ask is Firebase database is transaction based and I don't want to unnecessarily read the same data multiple times....

Answer (score 2):

Unlike the Realtime Database data, Cloud Firestore has accordong to [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline):

> For Android and iOS, offline persistence is enabled by default.

So you'll always have a **local** copy of your Cloud Firestore database on user's device. This means that the user will be able to query the database when the device is offline.

> Firebase always query the server or return from the local copy?

It doesn't matter if the data in your database is changing constantly or not, when the user is online, he will always query the data from the server and when offline, he will always query the data from the cache. If you are thinking to change this behaviour, you need to now that there is no way to stop the retrieval of the data from the cache while you are not connected to the server, as you cannot force the retrieval of the data from the cache while you're connected to the server.

> Firebase database is transaction based

When you are talking about [Firestore Transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions) it doesn't mean that you'll read the same data (documents) multiple times. But if you are going to use transaction there are a few things that you need to keep in mind. Regarding your reuquest, one of the most important is:

> Transactions will fail when the client is offline.

So, transactions are not supported for offline use and also it can't be cached or saved for later. This is because a transaction absolutely requires round trip communications with server in order to ensure that the code inside the transaction completes successfully.

Answer (score 0):

The Firestore SDK for Android has a [local cache](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline) that's enabled by default.  Read operations will come from cache if there are no updates on the server.